# How to delete old entries?

Tags: django

I have model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    obj = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    [...]
```

and I have for example 100 entries in db. I want delete all entries except most recent 6.
How to do it in ORM?

Comment: How do you define the most recent 6? what have you tried?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by first getting the date of the 6th most recent entry. Then delete everything that is older than this date.

```
max_date = MyModel.objects.order_by('-date')[5]
delete_qs = MyModel.objects.filter(date__lt=max_date)
# it might be a good idea to inspect the result at this point
# to ensure you are deleting the right stuff
delete_qs.delete()
```